# what language is dreamweaver written in?

Tags: dreamweaver

I was just wondering because I thought it was C++ but then I installed Dreamweaver CC and it required the Java Runtime to open. Does that mean it's written in Java or just parts of it or what?

Comment: May be some of the mechanism is written in java. But yes core components are written in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Adobe products are written in C++. But as i say some features may be written in java for cross-platforms.

[See this table](http://www.lextrait.com/vincent/implementations.html)